# Replace Image with Another Image While Maintaining Same Position On Object?

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, edit-mode

Is it possible to replace an image that is set on an object with another image in that exact same location and scale?

Basically, I have this picture on my wall of my room. I want to recreate the same room multiple times, except replace the image on the wall with another image while maintaining the same exact position and scale.

Can you do that in blender without having to manually import/add/scale an image?

This is what I mean where I have this object with the image. When I duplicate it, is there a way to replace that image (the rectangle outline) faster without having to readd/scale it to the same size every time.

[image]

Comment: you could open your 2 images (the former and the new one) into an image editor and make sure that they align perfectly, this way when you'll import the new one it will match

Comment: well right now I am adding the image to my room using image as planes addon, so is there an option where I can simply just add it again with the same scale?

Comment: if you select your first image as plane, open the Shader Editor, you'll see an Image Texture plugged into a Principled BSDF, you can just replace the image that is loaded in this Image Texture by the new one. If you've made sure, in an image editor, that these 2 images align perfectly, then the new one will replace the former one as you wish

Comment: so when I change the image on the image editor, it changes the previous room picture too since I just duplicated the room.

Comment: mmh not sure what you mean, when I was talking about an image editor I meant an app like Krita or Photoshop, sorry for not being clear. So in this editor, put the new image on a layer above the former one, move the new one so that it aligns with the former one, then save. In Blender open the image in the Image Texture of your Image as Plane and it should replace the former one and match perfectly

Comment: oh well in blender I'm making this huge animation, so basically I have to copy each object with my image, then right click on the image location, select my new image from my downloads, then scale the image to the correct size. So far it's working, just is quite slow, so was trying to figure out a more efficient process for duplicating and adding my images to the new objects without having to rescale them each time

Comment: I added an image to my question to give a visual.

Comment: if it's a new material with a new image, just duplicate the current material and replace the image with the new one? If you've made sure that the new image has the same size as the previous one it will replace it correctly

Comment: when I replace the image on the shader tab, it ends up changing the previous duplicate image too and makes both images pink

Comment: You need to create a new material before changing the image: https://zupimages.net/up/22/15/3q5q.jpg

Comment: hmm i guess that works, but seems like just deleting and adding the image manually is almost faster if not the same amount of time